# Using an alternative to WebBrowser control

Tags: c#

I'm currently using linux so I have problems using WebBrowser control in C#, I run MonoDevelop in Ubuntu 12.04, and apparently the WebBrowser control uses IE, so there's my problem, is there any way of grabbing the HTML from the website using HTTP functions then parse it in the box where I want it?

```
this.webBrowser1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.webBrowser1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point (0, 0);
this.webBrowser1.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size (20, 20);
this.webBrowser1.Name = "webBrowser1";
this.webBrowser1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size (404, 178);
this.webBrowser1.TabIndex = 0;
this.webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri ("http://url.net/a.php", System.UriKind.Absolute);
```

All I really need is a Linux/Unix compatible version of it :) Thanks!

Comment: You will be interested in looking into this http://www.mono-project.com/WebBrowser

Comment: http://awesomium.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not mine , you can read the url link

```
 public static String readWebLink(  String url)
            {
                System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
                byte[] data = client.DownloadData(url);
                String html = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                return html;

            }
```

or

```
   public static String readWebLink(  String url)
    {
     System.Net.WebClient webclient = new System.Net.WebClient();
     return  webclient.DownloadString(url);
     }
```

Thankyou